# use dateTimePIcker to set timer interval

Tags: c#, double, datetimepicker

I want to use dateTimerPicker Time format {mm:ss} and use it in timer.interval.

meaning converting the dateTimePicker value to double and back again.

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
timer.Interval = dateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

timer.interval is in milliseconds. (mm * 60 + ss) * 1000 = time in milliseconds.
Or easier is `DateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds`.

Perhaps it is also beter to use the TimeSpan object instead of the DateTime. Because you are not using the Date part of it. (Maybe for other reasons which I don't know)

You then can use the TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds property.

[TimeSpan on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Comment: DateTimerPicker dont use timespan

Comment: if you have to use DateTimePicker: DateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds